# ¿Contar consonantes de un String JAVA? (teniendo en cuenta números y signos)

Tags: java, condiciones

Necesito una función para contar consonantes. Pensé en recorrer el `String`, y teniendo la longitud de la frase, restar los espacios en blanco y vocales, así el resto de caracteres serían las consonantes, pero hay que tener en cuenta números y símbolos.

¿Alguna forma de contar que no sea contar cada consonante y tener que hacer un if con TODAS las consonantes?

```
int contador = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        
        if (array[i] == 'b' || array[i] == 'c' || ...){
            
            contador += 1;
    }
```

Supongo que hacer un `String` con todas las consonantes y compararlo también sirve. Pero no sé si hay una solución más sencilla

Comment: mmm tal vez la documentacion te sirva mucho mas??? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)

Comment: Por favor agrega un ejemplo de lo que necesitas realizar. Por ejemplo puedes almacenar los valores que no deseas contar y a continuación comparar cada carácter que tengas en tu frase.

Comment: Considera el [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Caracteres_imprimibles_ASCII) de las consonantes.

Comment: Usa un array de "valores permitidos", recorres tu String, compruebas si cada char existe en el array de valores permitidos, si existe sumas 1. Si buscas ayuda en SO, por favor recuerda que solo podemos ayudarte con problemas concretos, aquí no hacemos la tarea de nadie porque eso no sirve de nada. No se aprende copiando y pegando, se aprende "peleándose" con el código.

Comment: Esto puede ser realizando obteniendo los caracteres de la cadena, revisa charAt().}

Answer (score 2):

Para poder **contar consonantes de un String en JAVA**, puedes iterar cada carácter de la cadena detectando si este es consonante o no, para obtener cada carácter puedes usar:

**[charAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))**: Devuelve el valor `char` en el índice especificado de una cadena.

Puedes usar una expresión regular, para poder realizar la comparación y saber si es consonante o no, esto para evitar usar muchas comparaciones con otros.

```
  String cadena = "¿Contar consonantes de un String JAVA?";
  int contador = 0;

  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[\\W_aeiuoAEIOU0-9]+$");
  for(int i=0; i<cadena.length(); i++) {
      Matcher m = pat.matcher(String.valueOf(cadena.charAt(i)));
   if(m.find()) {
       //System.out.println("NO es consonante: "+cadena.charAt(i)); //No es consonante.
     } else {
         //System.out.println("Es consonante: "+cadena.charAt(i)); //Es consonante.
          contador++;//es consonante, incrementa contador.
     }
  }
  System.out.println("La cadena contiene " + contador + " consonantes." );
```

Salida:

```
La cadena contiene 20 consonantes.
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución alternativa, verificas cada elemento en una iteración, haciendo uso de las funciones integradas en Java para la clase **String**

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {  
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String vStrOracion = "Hello World!";
      String vStrVocal = "AEIOU";
      int vIntCont = 0;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < vStrOracion.length(); i++) {
          if (Character.isAlphabetic(vStrOracion.charAt(i)) &&
             !vStrVocal.contains(
                Character.toString(vStrOracion.charAt(i)).toUpperCase()
              ))
             vIntCont++;
   }
   System.out.println(vIntCont);
 } 
}
```

Sin embargo, la solución de **Cuauhtli** me parece más adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Te servirá una expresión regular? Aquí cree una función llamada `contarConsonantes`:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String cadena = "Caden12A)coN_:car$%acTeRE3-s";
        final Integer cantConsonantes = contarConsonantes(cadena);
        
        System.out.println(String.format("La cadena \"%s\", tiene \"%s\" consonantes.", cadena, cantConsonantes));
    }
    public static int contarConsonantes(String cadena) {
        final String consonants = cadena.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU0-9\\W_]", "");
        return consonants.length();
    }
}
```

Le pedimos que cuando encuentre alguna vocal (mayúsculas o minúsculas), un número, un caracter que no sea una palabra, y un guión bajo, lo elimine de nuestra cadena.

Y ya luego guardamos la cantidad de lo que resto, es decir, de las consonantes

Su ejecución resulta algo así:

```
La cadena "Caden12A)coN_:car$%acTeRE3-s", tiene "11" consonantes.
```

Answer (score -2):

supongamos tengamos la frase

```java
String frase = "prueba en string 123Test !$%%5kd kdj";
```

procederíamos con lo siguiente, recorrer cada posición y con esto verificar el carácter a comparar:

```java
String frase = "prueba en string 123Test !$%%5kd kdj";
int contador = 0;
for(int index = 0; index < frase.length; index++){
    //verifica si el caracter es igual espacio en blanco
    if(frase.charAt(index) == ' ') 
        continue;
    //verifica si el caracter es una vocal
    if(frase.charAt(index) == 'a' || frase.charAt(index) == 'e' || frase.charAt(index) == 'i' || frase.charAt(index) == 'o' || frase.charAt(index) == 'u') 
        continue;
    //verifica si el caracter es un signo
    if(frase.charAt(index) == '&' || frase.charAt(index) == '#' || frase.charAt(index) == '!' ) 
        continue;

    //ahora bien solo quedarian los datos que deseas contar por lo tanto solo aumentas tu contador
    contador++;

}
```

Ahora bien entiendo lo que hace `continue`, en si lo que hace es al entrar en uno de los `ìf` le indica al `for` que pase al siguiente valor y no continua ejecutando el código. En este caso solo va a aumentar el valor de contador cuando no ingresa en ningún `if`

Espero te sirva saludos.

> No recuerdo bien si es `String` o `string`. He estado trabajando en C#

Comment: Hola DavElsanto, diría que tu método está incompleto, ya que no contempla que existan muchos de los símbolos y tampoco dirime entre mayúsculas y minúsculas..

Comment: Si es por lo mismo se debería extender pero estaba respondiendo desde el trabajo para que se dé una idea. Por ejemplo se pueden agregan funciones para verificar los signos y mayúsculas de las vocales y alguna parte extra pero esa es la idea general en sí